# How can I post witin a controller to a delete function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, crud

I have a standard (CRUD generated) delete function

```
// GET: Posts/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            db.Posts.Remove(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I want to call this within the controller like this

```
if (totalVotes <= 5 && voteValue == -1)
{
    Delete(postId); //NOT WORKING
}
```

But this gets me the Delete GET function. Guess I have to do a post within the controller, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Move the delete code to a method and call that from multiple methods as needed.

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    DeletePost(id);            
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private void DeletePost(int id)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
    db.Posts.Remove(post);
    db.SaveChanges();            
}
```

and in some other method in the same controller

```
if (totalVotes <= 5 && voteValue == -1)
{
    DeletePost(postId); 
}
```

Note that, the `DeletePost` method does not return anything. So your calling method has to return some response back (if that method's return type is not void)

Comment: DeleteConfirmed is never called. When is it used? Is it safe to do a Delete function like this without [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]?

Comment: You do not directly call the private DeletePost method ? It will be invoked from another method ( Ex : DeleteConfirmed action method)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. You call the function DeletePost from your if-statement but never DeleteConfirmed. But you call DeletePost from DeleteConfirmed. Should I use DeleteConfirmed(postId)?

Comment: as i explained in the answer, you can call it from any other methods in this class(including deleteconfirm) . in the question, you have not mentioned where your if statement was !

Comment: I have a "standard" delete function to delete a post from the view (generated CRUD). I also have a vote function like stackoverflow (in the same controller) where I want to delete an post, depending on the next vote (the if statement). Of course I could put delete code in the if statement but sense I already have a delete post function I think it is better to reuse it.

Comment: Yes. That is why i suggested to move the code to delete the record to a private method which can be called from anywhere.